# Showing $F_{64}/F_2$ is Normal

Tags: field-theory

I need to show that $F_{64}/F_2$ is normal. So far I generated $F_{64}$ by doing $F_2[x]/(x^6+x+1)$. But I'm not sure where to go from here. I think what I need to do is show that $F_{64}$ is a splitting field for $x^6+x+1$? Though I'm not sure why just showing it for this one polynomial is enough to show that the extension is normal. And I've been trying to factor it but I don't see how to go about that?

Comment: Hint: splitting fields of separable polynomials are normal, and $F_{64}$ is a splitting field over $F_2$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Right, that's clear to me. I think $x^6+x+1$ is separable since gcd($x^6+x+1$,$x^5+1)$ = 1.  I wonder how to show though that $F_{64}$ is a splitting field over $F_2$.

Comment: Not *that* polynomial. There’s another one. Do you know what the multiplicative group of nonzero elements of a finite field looks like?

Comment: What's wrong with that polynomial, it's irreducible right? I think $x^6+x^3+x^2+x+1$ should be another example of an irreducible polynomial, anything where the sum of coefficients is odd. It's just the field minus {0} right? And it's cyclic.

Comment: The polynomial is fine, but it’ll be hard to prove $F_{64}$ is its splitting field. It’s much easier to use, say, $x^{64}-x$.

Comment: Oh I see. But don't we need $F_{64}$ to be a splitting field over $F_2$ specifically? So wouldn't we need it to split with a degree 6 polynomial that generates $F_{64}$ over $F_2$?

Comment: It needs to be the splitting field of some separable polynomial with coefficients in $F_2$; it doesn’t have to be the *smallest degree* polynomial that works, just *a* polynomial that works.

Comment: Oh that's cool. How is $x^{64}-x$ irreducible though? Aren't 0 and 1 roots? Do you mean $x^{64} -x - 1$?

Comment: It doesn’t have to be irreducible.

Comment: Oh that makes a lot more sense, I guess I'm getting all confused with the different theorems lol. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During my qualifying oral exam, I was asked to construct a field of order $27$; so I wrote one polynomial and invoked a certain result, but was asked to do a more constructive construction that did not invoke the existence of splitting fields. I found an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_3$ and did the usual construction. Great. Then I was given a different irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_3$ and was asked to prove the resulting extension was isomorphic to the one I had initially given. After 5 minutes of flailing to try to construct an explicit isomorphism, I was told to step back and look at the polynomial I had originally written down: $x^{27}-x$.

---

Basically: since a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field (in fact, of an integral domain) must be cyclic, the multiplicative subgroup of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is cyclic of order $p^{n}-1$, and therefore every nonzero element satisfies the polynomial $x^{p^n-1}-1$. Therefore, the elements of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ are all roots of $x^{p^n}-x$, and these are all the roots in an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_{p}$. And no strictly smaller field has all the roots, because this polynomial is separable (its derivative is $-1$). Thus, $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is the splitting field of $x^{p^n}-x$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$, and therefore it is normal (and unique up to isomorphism over $\mathbb{F}_p$).